# Html inline elements without content

Tags: html, element

For a very long time now I have being trying to  study HTMl alone using online tutorials which includes Youtube and Google as the case may be.I constantly come across one specific thing which some people will write code but leave some div and  closed without having to put anything in between like
the in the code below considering the span elements

```
<div class="wait overlay">
<div class="loader"></div>
</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">   
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- 
 toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
```

looking at the below  elements, they are just closed without anything in between them in which they are holding.

```
                <span class="sr-only">navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">website name</a> 
   </div>
```

I have tried a lot of search but it seems that i cant get the exact keyword to direct me to what will actually satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Those are elements that will (might get) filled in a dynamic manner if they are used / required at runtime. When instantiating them in a static manner like this (as opposed to injecting them in a dynamic manner) you do not have to care about their placement in the DOM tree.